# gson: deserialse json response without name

Tags: arrays, gson

i get a result of a response call somthing like this:

> [[15,"RAM SR2",2],[18,"HDD SH-1",1],[25,"Graphics Card",1]]

where an item ayyar have this structure: [id,name,qty]

how i can deserialse my response with Gson

Comment: You have an array containing 3 arrays.  You index, just like with any array.

Comment: can you give me an example how, plz?

Comment: `result = myArray[1][2];`.  Of course, GSON probably returns some sort of List, so you'd use the List's flavor of indexing.